Why can Express.js read some req.body variables and not others?
First, I am not currently using body-parser and I know that I need to use it. Second, my question is why are some of my variables able to be read through req.body WITHOUT body-parser but others show up undefined?
I have 5 variables: title(string), text(string), picturePath(object), fruit(string) and test(string).
When I console.log "title", "text", and "test" in the backend they show up with their correct values, while "picturePath" and "fruit" show up undefined. When I console.log in the frontend all the variables show up with their correct values. Can someone explain why only some change to undefined in the backend?
router.put("/:id/two", VerifyToken, upload.single("file"), async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const blogPostId = req.params.id;
        const { title, text, picturePath, fruit, test } = req.body;
        if (req.file === undefined) {
            const data = await BlogPostsModel.findByIdAndUpdate(blogPostId, { title, text });
            if (!data) {
                throw new Error('An error occurred while updating blog post')
            }
            res.status(200).json(data);
        }
        else {
            const data = await BlogPostsModel.findByIdAndUpdate(blogPostId, { title, text, picturePath: req.file.filename });
            if (!data) {
                throw new Error('An error occurred while updating blog post')
            }
            res.status(200).json(data);
        }
    }
    catch (error) {
        res.status(500).json({error: 'An error occurred while updating blog post...'})
        
    }
})

frontend PUT request function:
const UpdateBlogPost = async (e, title, text, picturePath, test) =>{
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(typeof(picturePath), typeof(title), typeof(text), typeof(fruit), typeof(test))

    try {
        const formdata = new FormData()
        formdata.append('file', picturePath)
        formdata.append('title', title)
        formdata.append('text', text)
        formdata.append('base', fruit)
        formdata.append('test', test)

        const response = await fetch(`${baseUrl}/blogPosts/${blogpostId}`, {
            method: "PUT",
            headers: { authorization: token},
            body: formdata
        })

        if (response.ok) {
            Navigate(`/blogPost/${blogpostId}`);
        }
    }
    catch(error){
        console.log(error);
    }
}


When you debug the code shown, what exact observed value does req.body contain?  When you test the request from a client (e.g. Postman), what exact value is sent in the request body?

@David I have updated my post to show the frontend request function. When I send in the frontend the variable "picturePath" shows it is an object with the correct file and "fruit" shows a string that returns "melon". In the backend they become undefined.

Depends how you are sending your data from POSTMAN or frontend. Anyways for json body request you should use  body-parser.
It seems like you're encountering some confusion regarding the behavior of variables in your Node.js backend when using req.body without body-parser. Let's clarify:
You mentioned that title, text, and test are showing up correctly in the backend when logged but picturePath and fruit are undefined. This is likely because title, text, and test are simple string variables, whereas picturePath and fruit might be objects or more complex data types.
In Express.js, to parse the incoming request body, you indeed need to use middleware like body-parser (for Express versions prior to v4.16, where it's included by default). Without body parsing middleware, Express doesn't parse the body of incoming requests automatically, hence req.body will be empty or undefined unless you've parsed it somehow.
The problem is because you put
formdata.append('base', fruit)
You put that the fruit should be "base" named, so the backed will take as "base", you should do if not

formdata.append('fruit', fruit)


the "fruit" variable is a string as well.

And how you are sending the data ? using form or body raw json?

What about the body parser ?

I have updated my post to show the frontend request function. I am aware that I will need body-parser, my question was why are some variables read correctly while the others are undefined without body-parser? It isn't because they are strings because the "fruit" variable is a string as well. I am just curious as to why some variables are readable and others aren't.

lol wow all I needed to do was match. Thank you! And I assume even though I changed picturePath to match file it still won't work because it is an object and not a string, and that is where body-parser comes into play, correct?
